# How to execute this step from Matlab in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix

In Matlab we can use the following code lines in order to set the entire last row and last column of  `1+N x 1+N` sized matrix `x` as `1`.

```
x=zeros((1+N,1+N))
x(1+N,1:N+1) = 1
x(1:N+1,1+N) = 1
```

What would be the equivalent way to get the similar result in python with and without using numpy? Thanks!

Comment: You say `get` but the code looks like you're setting the last row/column to 1...

Comment: mgilson, I think (i.e., am about 99% sure that) by "get ... as 1" S_H means "get ... to equal 1", i.e., "arrange for ... to equal 1", i.e., "set ... to 1".

Comment: @mgilson: Corrected that for ya! Thanks for pointing!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an array full of zeros: `x = numpy.zeros((1+N,1+N))`

To set one row or column to 1: e.g., `x[:,3] = 1`

Without using numpy, presumably you'd use nested lists. The easiest way to get a rectangular array of zeros is with a comprehension like this: `x = [m*[0] for i in range(n)]`; then you can replace one row of `x` by saying `x[3] = ...` but updating a whole column, or some but not all of a row, will require an explicit loop.